# How can I update my nested component's state using mount()?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme, jestjs, react-dom

I am trying to test if my component renders the Search component if the path is `/search`.

This is my test:

```
it('renders Search when the correct URL is provided', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/search']} initialIndex={1}>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  ).find(App);
  expect(wrapper.find(Search)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

`App.js` render function:

```
render() {
  const { loading } = this.state;
  let content;

  if (loading) {
    content = <Loading />;
  } else {
    content =
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<BookList data={this.state} onHandleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} onStarClick={this.starClick.bind(this)} />)} />
          <Route path="/search" render={() => (<Search data={this.state} onHandleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} onStarClick={this.starClick.bind(this)} />)} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problems I have already encountered while searching for solutions are:

1. Using shallow: I can update App's state. Switch throws an error saying that it doesn't have a Router, but it does and it's the MemoryRouter.
2. Using mount: I can't update App's state. Switch recognizes MemoryRouter.

App's `state.loading` default value is `true`, it is updated to `false` when `componentDidMount()` runs.

Any ideas how I could update App's state while using `mount` or a way to access `Search` using `shallow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem by refactoring my code and passing the content inside `else` to its own component:

```
const MainContent = (props) => {
  const { data, onHandleChange, onStarClick } = props;
  return(
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<BookList data={data} onHandleChange={onHandleChange} onStarClick={onStarClick} />)} />
      <Route path="/search" render={() => (<Search data={data} onHandleChange={onHandleChange} onStarClick={onStarClick} />)} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  )
};
```

Then I tested my route in `MainContent.test.js`:

```
it('renders <Search /> when path is `/search`', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/search']}>
      <MainContent data={body} onHandleChange={handleChange} onStarClick={starClick}/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  ).find(MainContent);
  expect(wrapper.find(Search)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Hopefully this might help someone who is having the same issue.